# How can I link a YouTube video into an existing iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

The webpage I'm building has a navbar down the left side, and when those links are clicked the content is displayed in an iframe that occupies most of the body of the page on the right. One of the links is to a YouTube video, however, when clicked the link does nothing. I have tried using the YouTube share code, embed code, and URL for the page containing the video, but with no success.

Here is how I have it formatted now:

```
<p><a class="one" href="URL" target="iframe_a"></a>Link Text</p>
```

For each of my other links this works fine. How can I make the embedded video only display when the link is clicked, or, how can I display the page containing the video when the link is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Example http://jsfiddle.net/0g169qdm/

```
<p><a class="one" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fr55ie7LE50" target="iframe_a">Link Text</a></p>
<iframe name="iframe_a" id="iframe_a"></iframe>
```

Comment: That's literally the same format as what I said I already have.